# load current values in entitytype field symfony 5

Tags: symfony, collections, entity

I have a many to many relationships (user, devices), then into user I have zero o more devices in a collectios. Then I have a user form with a device entitytype field that show all possible devices. Until here everything works fine.

Now I need to edit user, then in the device entitytype field I need to show all possible devices and highlight the current saved devices. For example if I have device 1,2,3,4,5 and options 2,3 are the current values I need to show 1,2,3,4,5 with 2,3 selected (highlighted).

Now when I get user entity it has a collections with the devices saved, but in the device field the devices saved is not selected (highlighted).

This is my controller (User=Usuario,Driver=Dispositivo):

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Usuario;

use App\Form\UsuarioType;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * @Route("/usu")
 */
class UsuarioController extends AbstractController
{


    /**
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="usuario_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, $id): Response
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $usuario = $entityManager->getRepository(Usuario::class)->find($id);

        //dd($usuario);
        $form = $this->createForm(UsuarioType::class, $usuario );
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('usuario_index');
        }

        return $this->render('usuario/edit.html.twig', [
            'usuario' => $usuario,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

}
```

This is my user entity values (option 2 is in the collections):

```
UsuarioController.php on line 49:
App\Entity\Usuario {#670 ▼
  -id: 1
  -id_usuario_k: 1
  -id_usuario_a: 1
  -dispositivos: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#690 ▼
    -snapshot: array:1 [ …1]
    -owner: App\Entity\Usuario {#670}
    -association: array:19 [ …19]
    -em: Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager {#566 …11}
    -backRefFieldName: "usuarios"
    -typeClass: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata {#673 …}
    -isDirty: false
    #collection: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#692 ▼
      -elements: array:1 [▼
        0 => App\Entity\Dispositivos {#703 ▼
          -id: 2
          -descripcion: "Disp2"
          -usuarios: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#705 ▶}
        }
      ]
    }
    #initialized: true
  }
}
```

This is my entity User (Usuario=User dispositivo=Driver)

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UsuarioRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UsuarioRepository::class)
 */
class Usuario
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id_usuario_k;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id_usuario_a;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Dispositivos", inversedBy="usuarios", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="UsuDisp",
     *  joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="usuario_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *  inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="dispositivo_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *  )
     */
    private $dispositivos;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dispositivos = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getIdUsuarioK(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id_usuario_k;
    }

    public function setIdUsuarioK(int $id_usuario_k): self
    {
        $this->id_usuario_k = $id_usuario_k;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdUsuarioA(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id_usuario_a;
    }

    public function setIdUsuarioA(int $id_usuario_a): self
    {
        $this->id_usuario_a = $id_usuario_a;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Dispositivos[]
     */
    public function getDispositivos(): Collection
    {
        return $this->dispositivos;
    }

    public function setDispositivos(ArrayCollection $dispositivos)
    {
      $this->dispositivos = $dispositivos;
  
      return $this;
    }
  
    public function addDispositivo(Dispositivo $dispositivo): self
    {
        if (!$this->dispositivos->contains($dispositivo)) {
            $this->dispositivos[] = $dispositivo;

        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function removeDispositivo(Dispositivo $dispositivo): self
    {
        if ($this->dispositivos->contains($dispositivo)) {
            $this->dispositivos->removeElement($dispositivo);
            $dispositivo->removeGroupe($this);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

This is my form code:

```
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('Drivers', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Driver::Class,
                'choice_label' => 'description',
                'placeholder' => 'Select a device',
                'multiple' => true,
                'empty_data' => '',

            ]);

    }
```

This is my screen (option 2 is saved):
[image]

I will appreciate some help.

Comment: Do you have a property named `'Drivers'` or methods named `getDrivers`,  `addDriver`, & `removeDriver`? If so, please add to your question. Also please copy and paste your dump it will be much more helpful than using an image of text.

Comment: You should also add your code for the controller method handling the form.

Comment: I added controller and entity code. It is in spanish, in my original question I translate usuario = user and dispositivo = driver.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I have to add choice_value='descripcion', the same as choice_label.

I don't know why, what is symfony doing internally ?